# Euler Method Question

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This is the question:

Find the error for Euler method of solving initial value problem

$$y′=\frac{y}{x+1},\quad y(0)=1$$

on the interval $[0,1]$.

I'm confused by the question.  Am I supposed to find something that prevents me from using the Euler method to solve this problem?  If it is, how do I work through the problem to find the error?  Thanks.

Comment: Every numerical method has some sort of error since you are using a numerical algorithm. Clear?

Comment: For a numerical method "error" means the difference between the true value (in this case obtained by solving the differential equation and evaluating the result at $x=1$) and the value obtained using the numerical method (in this case Euler's method, again at $x=1$).

Comment: I put the equation into display math mode, because a previous (IMHO misguided) edit replaced a perfectly legible formula by a fraction with tiny, barely readable numerator/denominator. If the OP does not want to have the DE mangled in this way, I recommend rolling back to the original form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

- Write out the numerical formula using Euler's Method, and do, say, ten iterations, that is, $h = 0.1$.
- Compare that numerical result at each step to the exact solution to the DEQ:

$$y(x) = x + 1$$

Comment: Killer hints, Amzoti. :D

Comment: I don't need a complete solution, your tip was more than good enough to push me in the right direction.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Nice work and nice feedback! +1